# Parse different sources differently

Tags: javascript, oop, parsing

Let's say I wanted to parse information from different radio stations websites (the songs that were just played) and store them in a database. The websites differ (obviously), so I need to parse them differently. My way to do that is to create a super class "RadioStation" with the common functions and derive subclasses for each website in which I define the special parse function. However I don't think that's the right way to go because i would have to write 100+ subclasses. What is the correct solution here?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to make classes for single functions. Don't think too OOP in javascript. Just store a map radiostationid -> parsefunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and write an intelligent parser or you could write the 100+ subclasses, there is no simple solution to trying to parse data from different sources in different formats.

Though I would not be surprised if webradios would provide data in some kind of standard format (SOAP, XML, something...) as I suppose there are already quite a few applications that use it.